# Determine closure, limit points and isolated points in the co-finite topology

Tags: general-topology

Could somebody please verify if my solution is correct?

#### Problem

Let $\mathbb{R_{cf}}$ denote the co-finite topology on $\mathbb{R}$. Let
$$A_{N} = \{ \frac{1}{n} \ | \ 1 \le  n \le N\} \cup \{0\}$$

For each $N \in \mathbb{N}$, determine the closure, limit points, and isolated points of $A_{N}$ in $\mathbb{R}_{cf}$.

#### Solution

##### a) Closure

I claim that the closure of $A_N$ is $A_N$ itself, since it is closed. Consider $U = \mathbb{R} - A_N$. Since $U^c = A_N$ is finite, $U$ is open, hence $A_N$ is closed.

##### b) Limit points

I claim that $A_N$ does not contain any limit points. Assume $x$ is a limit point of $A_N$. Since $A_N$ is closed, $x \in A_N$. Now consider $U = \mathbb{R} - (A_N - \{x\})$. Clearly $U$ is open and $x \in U$. But $U \cap (A_N-\{x\}) = \emptyset$, contradiction.

##### c) Isolated points

Isolated points are those $x \in A_N$ such that $\{x\}$ is open in $A_N$ seeing it as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}_{cf}$. I claim that each point $x$ in $A_N$ is an isolated point, since:
$$\{x\} = A_N \cap U$$

where the $U =  (\mathbb{R}- (A_N - \{x\}))$, which is open in $\mathbb{R_{cf}}$

Comment: Seems good to me!